# How do I clear the Dragon in Level 5 of the Endless Paths?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

*Spoilers* ahead, few hours into game!

In game playing for 17 days, slain 259 enemies. Party all level 5.

I've gotten to Endless Paths of Old Nua level 5 and I can't beat this dragon no matter how hard I try. Am I supposed to beat him now or should I pay him a visit later?

Comment: OP in this question - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285759/how-to-beat-the-enemy-on-main-hall-in-endless-path-of-od-nua-level-7 got as far as 7 level on lev. 5!

Answer (score 4):

The Endless Paths is a 15 level *optional* dungeon of ever increasing difficulty. The bottom levels include some of the most difficult content in the game. It's *possible* to get further than you are at the level you're at -positioning and gear matters more than anything - but it's very difficult to do so, and really, there's no reason to force it. If you can't handle it now, come back later.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following (I had a character that was a rogue).

Just before the room with the dragon, there is a room with a pool of blood. On the right hand side of this room there is a doorway. I placed my party inside the room on the right and had Eder (The fighter) inside the room with the pool of blood. I then snuck forwards with my rogue and did a sneak attach immediately on the nearest Xaurip (This draws the whole rooms aggro) I then invis'd (A rogue talent) and ran back to my party, I then moved Eder into the doorway to block the enemy from getting to my squishy priest and wizard.

I then used the first level priest spell "Withdraw" make Eder invisible (and heal him back to full). While invisible he can't take damage and he blocks the enemy from rushing at your party.

While he is invisible for 20 secods, attack the enemy with ranged weapons and spells.

Answer (score 2):

Level 5 is a little low level to explore the endless path. I did clean all level to 6 while being level 10. I would recommend waiting a little as the reward is not really a top item. Instead, build the gardian lodge if it is not done and ask the gardian for primes. He will give you 4 people to kill and these fights will help you level up really fast before going back to the dragon. It worked pretty well for me.

If you are still trying to do it, my strategy against all strong opponents surrounded by weaklings is to make your party wait in a corridor where you can only be attacked by two opponents at a time. Then trigger the combat by sending a ranged weapon user attack the first enemy you see. The rest of the ennemies will line up to kill you but two at a time which makes the combat much easier. I use Eder and Kana as the tanks as they are pretty good once armored and shielded. Then Durance will heal them all the time while Aloth cast everything he's got. I also add a cypher and a ranger to arrow from behind or cast powerful spells on spell user backing up your opponents.

Do not forget to buy some good food to increase resistance and attributes. This should do it. It worked pretty well for Raedric that i fought from the door of his dead wife bedroom ^_^;

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally dropped down on well just tonight, I was planning to go floor by floor. Ended up killing Drake with level 5 party on hard only. Cipher with 2h gun kept the drake on stun most of the fight. Killed mages first and then proceeded to clean up after.  Party was Eder, Aloth, Kana, Durance and Sagani.  Eder tanked center with Durance behind him equipped with pike for reach; both wearing plates.  Aloth was free to do some fireballs and chill fog while the rest sniped the mages.  Used mind blades and Kana's white worms to clean up after the Drake was down.

Answer (score 1):

I had My PC as a Barbarian, Eder, Aloth, Durance, Kana, and another custom character which was a rogue.

All were level 6, minus my rogue, who was only 5.
I set an ambush in the room before the blood well that you can fall into on a floor a couple levels up. What I did was clear out the immediate area so that my people would not be interrupted by even more baddies. Then set my 3 front line guys (Barbarian, Eder and Durnace) Near the door, but with some stand off. Kana and Aloth were placed further back in the room as both of them are ranged. I had my rogue set a trap towards the right corner of the door (I used a poison gas trap for AOE and decent damage) then moved the rogue to attack the Xipauslaksdk Champion. Once combat was initiated I moved my rogue over to Aloth and Kana. Aloth prepared a fireball just as the Drake was entering the room. Once it hit, I swarmed my front line to the door to create a funnel and stop enemies from entering the room. Everyone but Aloth focused solely on the Drake. Aloth lobbed another Fireball past the dragon into the huge crowd of Xipsaoskdoksldk guys. I made sure to use every single special skill I had at my disposal to cause damage to the Drake. He puked fire once and only hit Durance and Barbarian. Once the Drake had died only 2 Xipaosidokslr remained. One was in the room with me and the other was a High Priest who had not been aggro'd probably because he was standing near the stairs down.

I've since switch Durance to ranged weapons because he kept getting killed. So I have 2 Melee to tie up anyone that comes near and 4 support with a mixture of bows, guns and wand to deliver some serious point damage.

Most things I encounter don't survive the first volley. Its been very effective so far.

I hope this helps you. I just cleared the 7th floor and will probably get back up to the story. I think I have done most everything I can prior to getting to Defiance Bay.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I defeated the Drake (that isn't a full grown dragon) with a party of level 6 (and a level 5 hired priest) without much difficulty. I can't say if I got lucky, but I did notice he only breathed once.

Make sure to have your priest cast circle of protection, consecrated ground and maybe hold off on casting radiance until the breath lands. The cipher's chain cast attack and the mage chain missile attack were really handy here. The drake went down first, after being targeted by my Paladin, fighter and ranged; then I cleaned up the smaller critters.

Comment: awesome how your level 6 party could clear a drake and its 6-8 henchmen ( 2 mages, 2 champions and 3 skirmishers cant remember what else was in the room). and even more awesome that the drake only breathed fire once on you. I cleared this encounter with a lvl 9 party and by the end i had only my monk standing. everybody else was K.O.ed. Had pretty decent gear also.

Comment: My guys are level 8 now, with the priest still a level behind at 7. We're down on the 8th floor, but I've stopped pushing and gone back to other sidequests and the story, I haven't completed chapter one yet. I started to find I couldn't disarm traps on floor 8, which is a large part of my leaving for a bit.