# How to beat the enemy on main hall in Endless Path of Od Nua Level 7?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've been spending hours beating this floor. I can't get through the main hall, there is too many enemies. I tried leading them on a narrow doorstep to have them funneled but their spells really gets me down. Specially my melee are being mind controlled and the teleporting blights.

I am using Aloth (lvl5), Kana (lvl5), Durance(lvl5), Eder (lvl5), a hired barbarian (lvl4) and my main character is a wizard (lvl5).

The enemy are so many I don't know who's casting what.  Any ideas? Please share your strategy.

Comment: I don't remember that particular battle, but getting all the way through the Paths required leaving several times to do more quests and level up when I did it. You might just be up to the point where it's time to leave and come back.

Comment: I am too weak to face them all. And that's what I just did.

Comment: Yeah I bailed on level 8 with my party at xp level 6ish. I definitely had to use choke points, traps, and lots of buffs to get through the last section of level 7. Once the paths get too hard, it's probably best to return to other quests for a couple of xp levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't remember that particular battle, and it's been some time since I've played this game. Perhaps you could beat it with your current party with a great battle plan. I can't help you with that.

What I *can* tell you is that you shouldn't expect to get all the way through the paths just as soon as you get access to them. The bottom is much harder than the top, and you will need to be significantly stronger to beat it than you will need to be to start the first level.

You should leave to continue with your various quests every few levels. You'll find occasional exits back to the surface as you go. Treat these as checkpoints for returning next time.

When you come back, you'll find things much easier. Even if you can't track all the effects as they happen, your warriors should have better defenses to keep from getting mind controlled, and your back-line should be tougher to deal with teleporting enemies, which will hopefully be stopped by all the new crowd control you've picked up anyway.